# Refresh worksheet after writing from ListBox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, refresh, updates

I'm using below code to add items from `ListBox` to `Sheet1`. Everything is working, but after I click "add" the worksheet is not refreshing. The changes (added rows) I see only when I close my form.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wbc As Workbook
    Dim wsc As Worksheet

    Set wbc = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsc = wbc.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim addme As Range
    Dim x, y As Integer

    Set addme = Application.Selection

    For x = 0 To Me.lbsourceList.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lbsourceList.Selected(x) Then

            addme.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert            

            wsc.Range(Cells(addme.Row, "C"), Cells(addme.Row, "C")).Offset(1).Value = Me.lbsourceList.List(x, 0)
            wsc.Range(Cells(addme.Row, "I"), Cells(addme.Row, "I")).Offset(1).Value = Me.lbsourceList.List(x, 1)

            Set addme = addme.Offset(1, 0)

        End If
    Next x

    For y = 0 To Me.lbsourceList.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lbsourceList.Selected(y) Then Me.lbsourceList.Selected(y) = False
    Next y

End Sub
```

Can the worksheet be updated/refreshed after code is run?

Comment: You could try `Workbooks("your_wb_name").RefreshAll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worksheet should update even if the form is open and doing something. See the minimal example below (with a `Userform`, one `Listbox` and one `CommandButton`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For lngCounter = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        ws.Cells(lngCounter + 1, 1).Value = Me.ListBox1.List(lngCounter, 0)
    Next lngCounter

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "foo"
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "bar"
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "baz"

End Sub
```

Screenshot:

[image]

In your code, it is not clear when you turn `ScreenUpdating` back on - so that is something to be aware of.